# Advanced Loop & Merge in Qualtrics - Multiple random fields

Tags: loops, random, graphics, survey, qualtrics

I have a somewhat cumbersome Qualtrics question about randomization/Loop & Merge.

I am trying to run a study where participants answer questions about 10 different scenarios, each of which has two variants (call them A and B). All of these are given by displaying a different .jpg file above a set of the same 3-4 questions. We'd like to randomize whether they see A or B for each individual scenario, but ensure that they see each scenario once. We'd also like to intersperse 4 filler scenarios (only one variant each).

So the survey flow would look something like this:

- Random scenario 1 of 10 (randomly A or B)
- Random scenario 2 of 10 (randomly A or B)

  - Random filler 1 of 4
- Random scenario 3 of 10 (randomly A or B)
- Random scenario 4 of 10 (randomly A or B)

  - Random filler 2 of 4
- Random scenario 5 of 10 (randomly A or B)
- Random scenario 6 of 10 (randomly A or B)

  - Random filler 3 of 4
- Random scenario 7 of 10 (randomly A or B)
- Random scenario 8 of 10 (randomly A or B)

  - Random filler 4 of 4
- Random scenario 9 of 10 (randomly A or B)
- Random scenario 10 of 10 (randomly A or B)

I know how this would work with question or choice randomization, and I know how to do a simple Loop & Merge, but this has me stumped. Is there any way to do this without using a clunky fix such as duplicating the question block ~14 times?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I may have a solution, but a couple of questions first to see if it would work. Is the only difference between A and B in each of the scenarios the image? Can the fillers be fixed (not randomized, always shown in the same order)?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's not critical that the fillers be randomized. And yes, the difference between variants (conditions) A and B is simply whether it is one of two images corresponding to each scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set up ten randomizers, one for each scenario, in the survey flow. For each randomizer pick one of two embedded data blocks - block A or block B:

```
scenario1 = A
scenario1_img = [insert url of image A here]
```

.

```
scenario1 = B
scenario1_img = [insert url of image B here]
```

Create a single select multiple choice question before the loop & merge block with the following choices:

```
${e://Field/scenario1_img}
${e://Field/scenario2_img}
[insert filler 1 image url here]
${e://Field/scenario3_img}
${e://Field/scenario4_img}
[insert filler 2 image url here]
${e://Field/scenario5_img}
${e://Field/scenario6_img}
[insert filler 3 image url here]
${e://Field/scenario7_img}
${e://Field/scenario8_img}
[insert filler 4 image url here]
${e://Field/scenario9_img}
${e://Field/scenario10_img}
```

Then add advanced randomization to the question to randomize the scenarios:

```
{randomized}
{randomized}
[insert filler 1 image url here]
{randomized}
{randomized}
[insert filler 2 image url here]
{randomized}
{randomized}
[insert filler 3 image url here]
{randomized}
{randomized}
[insert filler 4 image url here]
{randomized}
{randomized}
```

Hide the question using JavaScript (it should be on the same page as another question, otherwise the script also has to click the Next Button) and make sure it is NOT forced response.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    $(this.questionId).hide();
});
```

Set up the loop & merge block to loop based off the displayed choices in the question above. Do not randomized the loop. If additional fields are needed for piping add them.

Pipe the images into an img tag in a question's text:

```
<img src="${lm://Field/1}">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is extremely helpful. I've set up the survey flow and embedded data as you've recommended, but I'm still having trouble getting the photos to display. I can get the img tag to work if I simply insert a URL (as opposed to a piped URL), but I'm getting blank space when using the Loop & Merge field. Adding graphics manually and then using display logic (e.g., when ${e://Field/scenario1_img} is Current Loop plus when ${e://Field/scenario1} equals A) also doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: It works when I try it.  So, I think something is probably wrong in your loop & merge setup. ${lm://Field/1} shouldn't be blank.  Try piping it outside the img tag and it should be a url to an image.

Comment: Ah -- finally caught my mistake. Made a silly oversight in the flow ordering. Works like a charm!